# Ruby class using attr_accessor and initialize method

Tags: ruby

Working toward making a small command line script in Ruby, where the 
user provides a few pieces of information related to restaurants, and
computed info gets returned.

Currently I have the following code:

```
class Restaurant
 attr_accessor :name :type :avg_price
 def initialize(name, type, avg_price)
   @name = name
   @type = type
   @avg_price = price
 end
 end
```

### Question 1

If we used `attr_accessors` method to declare `type`, and `price`, and `name`
Why is the Initialize method necessary? Is this because we need to set the
inputed values to it?

### Question 2

There is a sub-class called `RestaurantList` followed by `< Array` in the code. What is the function of this?

The Array class is not defined in the code? Is it a built in class in ruby called `Array`?  If so, what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Question 1

The `attr_accessor` method is a short cut to declaring variable accessible outside the
block within the method.

The `initializer` method in ruby is the method to be called when someone initializes
something of that class, i.e. `chipotle = Restaurant.new 'Chipotle', 'Mexican', 8.00`

### Question 2

`Array` is indeed a class built into Ruby, (built in classes generally referred to as the Ruby Standard Library, see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) for the MRI 1.9.3 documentation on the `Array` class.  You do not need to do any kind of special inheritance in order the use the `Array` class though.  The language is defined in a manor such that things such as string, hashes, arrays, and other commonly used classes do not need to be inherited.

That said, these are able to be overloaded.  Don't be surprised the day you find something that looks like an array but has alternate functionality.

### Other Notes

One thing to keep in mind when you approach Ruby programming is that *everything* is an object.  You will often hear this but it difficult to comprehend when you first dive but still important to keep in mind that *everything* can be mapped back to the `Object` class in Ruby, see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html) for documentation on the `Object` class.

Comment: Thank you so much, It is very clear now. how long did it take you to learn to program with ruby by yourself? thank you.

Comment: @user1556385 It took me about 4 months to learn _Ruby_, to give a little more perspective it took me about a month to learn _php_.  I defiantly do not have as good of a handle on it still as I would like (specifically the ability to utilize Ruby meta programming effectively), but remember everyone learns at their own rate.  Most people I have talked about learning Ruby describe the day "it just clicked", just keep at it, keep posting on stack (the community here is really great!) and one day it will just click!

Comment: Thank you so much for lighting my day, I'm a smart student, did good job using C language long time ago in 2005, with ruby it looked to me like PHP when i watched Lynda.com training class. a guy from ukraine wrote me a simple yet functional class script to add restaurant and type and price on command line and then print the list on screen, it was so clear to get idea of OOP and how to use the method for actions and actions start when he wrote the loop do statment. With Lynda.com dvd, i got confused the only difference than the guy code that lynda script used txt file to store it with search

Comment: I did, but it says i don't have the Reputition or something, Once i get to that level I'll make sure i do it. i already tried to do it before you notice that.